# How to serialize 'null' value?

Tags: java, serialization

In our company we write a simple serializer/deserializer in Java. Does anybody know what is the best way to serialize a `null` value?

Comment: Serialize to what? binary? XML?

Comment: @Eric Serialize to null.

Comment: You must contextualize your question!!!

Comment: Agree with Eric Petroelje and djechelon.

Answer (score 21):

### String

```
"null"
```

### XML

```
<null null="null">null</null>
```

### JSON

```
{"null": null}
```

### JSONP

```
null({"null": null})
```

### Binary

```
0x00000000
```

### YAML

```
null: null
```

### jQuery

```
$(null);
```

### ASCII

```
\0
```

### Unicode

```
\u0000
```

### URL

```
null://null.null
```

Any other formats you'd like me to cover?

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to say that I want to serialize 'null' to binary. One possible solution is to write additional byte before every object which shows is it null or not. Does somebody know better solution? (that requiers less bytes than +1 for every object)

Comment: @avmatis: what encoding are you using? There is no one "this is my data, in binary" representation. Unless you're using a standard encoding scheme, it's up to _you_ to determine how to represent nulls.

Comment: @avmatis: If null is also a valid value for your binary data I don't know how you can signify the difference without additional data. Unless your serialized data is bit-addressable I don't know how your 'is-null' flag can be smaller than a byte. You could pack multiple 'field-is-null' flags into a single byte.

Comment: It's probably worth showing how it's done in some well known binary-oriented data formats like ASN.1, bencoding (what bittorrent uses) and protobuf (what Google uses for IPC).

Comment: Loving how redundant and verbose the XML version is (as usual).